# How to use ActiveRecord's INCLUDES when looping over an Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following:

```
@rooms = current_user.rooms
```

Then I need to build a JSON object so I do:

```
render :json => room_json_index(@rooms)
```

Then to build the JSON object:

```
def room_json_index(rooms)

    @roomList = Array.new

    rooms.each do |room|
      @roomList << {
        :id => room.id,
        :user_id => room.user_id,
        :user_count => room_members.length,
        :user_photos => room_members.collect { |room_member|
          {
            :id => room_member.user.id,
            :photo => room_member.user.photo(:thumb),
            :name => room_member.user.full_name
          }
        }
      }
    end

    @roomList.to_json
end
```

Problem here is that in every loop of rooms.each, rails keeps hitting the data for the same user objects. Is that necessary. I see in the logs that it is caching but I'd rather rails not even have to thinking about it.

```
  roomMember Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "room_members".* FROM "room_members" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "room_members"."user_id" WHERE ("room_members".room_id = 143) AND (users.guest = false OR users.guest = true AND users.fname IS NOT NULL OR users.id = 3)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 69 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 70 LIMIT 1
Room
```

Rails in the logs is repeating the request above over and over, looking for the same records over and over. Any ideas on how this can be optimized?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems your data model is like

```
class User << AR::Base
   has_many :room_members
   has_many :rooms,:through=>:room_members,:include=>:users
   ......
end
class Room << AR::Base
   has_many :room_members
   has_many :users,:through=>:room_members
   ......
end
class RoomMember << AR::Base
   belongs_to :room 
   belongs_to :user 
   ......
end
```

you can load user when load room

```
class User << AR::Base
   has_many :room_members
   has_many :rooms,:through=>:room_members,:include=>:users
   ......
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it results in an error: "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"

Comment: I updated it to include => :user and that stopped the error though the queries have not changed

Comment: Actually when I do the include user in Room for has many room_members that did it>! THank you